# Converting SAS dataset to pipe delimited text file with double quote for text attributes

Tags: sas, dataset

I found a macro to convert SAS dataset to pipe delimited text file with double quote for text attributes, but couldn't figure out how to add the attribute name/header in the text file.  Appreciate any help you could offer. 
below is the macro generated the text file (pipe delimited with double quote for text attributes) without the attribute name.

```
%macro csvQuoteChars(lib=,dset=,outPath=);
proc contents data=&lib..&dset out=vars(keep=name varnum type);

 run;
proc sql print;
    select (strip(name)) into :vars separated by '|' from vars
    order by varnum;
quit;

 %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(vars));
 %let nobs = %sysfunc(attrn(&dsid,nlobs));

 data _null_;
  set &lib..&dset;
  file "&outPath\&lib..&dset..txt" dsd dlm='|';

  %do i=1 %to &nobs;
      %let rc = %sysfunc(fetchobs(&dsid,&i));
      %let vName = %sysfunc(getvarc(&dsid,1));
      %let vType = %sysfunc(getvarn(&dsid,2));
      %put &=vName &=vType;

      %if &vType = 2 %then %do;
          put (&vName) (~) @;
      %end;
      %else %if &vType = 1 %then %do;
          put &vName @;
      %end;

      %if &i = &nobs %then %do;
          put ;
      %end;

  %end;

 run;

 %let dsid = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));

%mend csvQuoteChars;
%csvQuoteChars(lib=ed,dset=stopoverchg_201709,outPath=d:\temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

SAS will do it by default for values that contain the delimiter, so you don't have to do all character values unless that's a requirement I suppose. However, this will export the file correctly.

```
data class;
set sashelp.class;
if name='Alfred' then name = 'Al|fred';
run;

proc export data=class outfile='/folders/myfolders/class.txt'    dbms=dlm replace;
delimiter='|';
run;
```

Comment: thank you Reeza! i didn't intend to separate name by a pipe, but rather to add the header (without quote) to my text output.  let me know if you have other tips.

Comment: This does both though.

Answer (score 0):

`Export` per @Reeza is far simpler.

The macro can be changed to also output a header line with the variable names.  The macro populates the macro variable `vars` with a pipe delimited list of variable names, and then never uses it.

Add this line to the `data _null_` after `file` statement:

```
if _n_ = 1 then put "&vars";
```

Comment: this is very helpful!  how do i add header line (without quote) in the text file?

Answer (score 0):

You have over complicated the code generation part of the problem.  You just need to generate a put statement like:

```
put name ~ sex ~ age height weight ;
```

So make macro variables to help with that. You can also make the information you need for the headers.  I am assuming you also want quotes around the header values. Include VARNUM in the select list to avoid PROC SQL warning about sorting by a value not selected.

```
proc sql noprint;
select varnum
     , quote(trim(name))
     , catx(' ',name,case when (type=2) then '~' else ' ' end)
into :dummy
   , :headers separated by '|'
   , :varlist separated by ' '
from vars
order by varnum
;
quit;
```

Then your step to write the data is just:

```
data _null_;
  set &lib..&dset;
  file "&outPath\&lib..&dset..txt" lrecl=2000000 dsd dlm='|';
  if _n_=1 then put %sysfunc(quote(&headers),%str(%')) ;
  put &varlist;
run;
```

Comment: thanks, tom! tried this but the text file still doesn't contain header, am i missing anything?

Comment: To debug a macro definition turn on the MPRINT option before calling the macro. Then you can see the code that is generated.  That should make it easier to see what is wrong.  If you are getting no header row at all then either you are looking at the wrong text file or the IF THEN statement is typed wrong.  The condition is testing if the the automatic data step iteration variable  `_n_`  is 1.